# python html replacement in list does not work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code which is load all the td from a md file and search for a specific partner. Part of the code is the below

```
html_string = html.replace('&nbsp;', '')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
    tds = soup.findAll("td", {"class":"confluenceTd"}) # Find all td tags
    temp_holder={} # Get a temp dictionary

    html_as_list = list(html_string)
    html_join = "".join(html_as_list)
    prev_tag = []

 

    for td_name in tds:
...code ommited...
```

```
...code ommited...
            #print("TD name: ",td_name)
            tag_index = '<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">'
            end_tag = '</td>'
          
            get_tag_value = str(td_name.text.strip())         
            get_text_index = html_string.index(get_tag_value) # Get the index which text start 
            position_f = get_text_index - len(tag_index) # Get the index of the first character of the line "**<**" in our case

            full_tag = tag_index + get_tag_value + end_tag # Will print <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3103</td>
            #print(html_string.index(str(position_f)))

            result1 = search_j(get_tag_value) # Get the text from p tag and check if it has jira issue
            if result1 == -1:
                continue
 
            az_id = str(query_a(result1))         

            res1 = re.sub(result1, " #"+az_id+" ", full_tag) # Will return <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> #11111 </td>
            #print("Add key: ", position_f, " values: ",res1)

 

            # Check if there is any duplicate value
            # If douplicate exists get the position of in the original list
            if get_tag_value in prev_tag:
                dup = list_duplicates_of(html_join, get_tag_value)
                for dupl in dup:
                    position_s = dupl - len(tag_index)
                    temp_holder[position_s] = res1
            else:
                temp_holder[position_f] = res1       
            #print(res1)
            prev_tag.append(get_tag_value)

    for html_keys, html_values in temp_holder.items(): #Replace the old line with the new one
        #print(html_keys + len(html_values))
        #sys.exit()
        html_as_list[html_keys] = html_values
        print("P: ",html_keys, "V: ",html_values)

    html_fin = "".join(html_as_list)
    
    return html_fin


filename = 'PoPs.md'

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    html_string = f.read()
 
result = check_td(html_string)

save_filename="test.md"
#
w = open (save_filename, "a")
w.write(str(result))
w.close()
```

I use a temporary dictionary in order to save the update value as below
key: is the position of the first character "<" in our case
value: is the update value

The print will show:

```
P: 2651  V: "<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> #11111 </td>"
```

The final result are saved in a file which are the below

```
...output ommited...
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> #11111 </td>td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3103</td>
...output ommited...
```

As you can see it go and replace ONLY the **<** instead the whole line.

I expect to replace

```
"<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3103</td>" with "<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"> #11111 </td>"
```

What can am I missing in order to make it work correctly?

Any ideas?

Comment: All problem is because you expect too much - using `html_as_list = list(html_string)` you convert it to list of chars - simply see `print( html_as_list `) - and when you use `html_as_list[html_keys] = ...` then you replace single element on this list which is single char. It would need rather to use slice `html_as_list[html_keys:end_of_string] = ... ` but this works only if both strings are the same size. You could use normal `text.replace(...)` but it will move other elements in string and you would have to replace before searching next element.

Comment: maybe you should rather use functions in beautifulsoup to replace tags.

Comment: @furas how can I do that with beautiful soup

Answer (score 0):

All problem is because you expect too much.

Using `html_as_list = list(html_string)` you create list of chars like

```
[..., "<", "t", "d", " ", "c", "o", "l", "s", "p", "a", "n", ...]
```

and when you use `html_as_list[html_keys] = ...` then you replace single element on this list which is a single char.

You could try to use slice `html_as_list[html_keys:position_f] = list(text)` but it will change size of list if you put longer/shorter text and it will change position of other elements.

You could try to use normal `text.replace()` but it will also change length of string and next elements will be in different place so you would have to replace it before you will search next element.

---

If you want to replace text or tag in HTML then simply use `BeautifulSoup` for this

```
  item.string = "new text"
```

Function `find_all` (and other functions) gives you reference to element in HTML tree so you can change values in original HTML.

**BTW:** it has to be `.string`, not `.text`

---

Minimal working example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">A</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">B</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">C</td>
"""

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')

tds = soup.find_all('td', class_='confluenceTd')

for item in tds:
    if item.string == 'B':
        item.string = 'Hello World'
        
html = str(soup)
print(html)
```

Result (it puts `Hello World` in place of `B`)

```html
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">A</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">Hello World</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">C</td>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This version gets single `td` (`Element.Tag`) from `tds`, convert `Element.Tag` to string, replace text in this string, convert new string back to `Element.Tag` and replace `td` in `soup` - so it doesn' need to work with full HTML as string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re

html = """
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3102</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Special: <a href="">DDD-3103</a></td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3104<a href="">see more</a></td>
</tr>
"""

def search_j(text):
    """Simulate functon."""
    result = re.search('DDD-\d+', text)
    print('result:', result)
    if result:
        return result[0]    
    return -1
    
def query_a(item):
    """Simulate functon."""
    data = {'DDD-3102': 1102, 'DDD-3103': 1103, 'DDD-3104': 1104}
    return data[item]

def test_bs(html):
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
    
    tds = soup.find_all('td', class_='confluenceTd')
    
    for item in tds:
        # convert `Element.Tag` to `string`
        item_html = str(item)
        #print('item_html:', item_html)

        # search `jira`        
        result = search_j(item_html)
        if result == -1:
            continue
        
        # get `id` for `jira`
        az_id = str(query_a(result))
        
        # replace it
        new_item_html = item_html.replace(result, " #"+az_id+" ")
        #print('new_item_html:', item_html)
        
        # convert `string` back to `Element.Tag`
        new_item = BS(new_item_html, 'html.parser')
        
        # replace `item` in `soup`
        item.replace_with(new_item)
            
    print(soup)

test_bs(html)
```

Before:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3102</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Special: <a href="">DDD-3103</a></td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">DDD-3104<a href="">see more</a></td>
</tr>
```

After:

```
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"> #1102 </td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">Special: <a href=""> #1103 </a></td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"> #1104 <a href="">see more</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is that I can have more characters before the actual ID. For example "this is a text a very big test DDD-12345 and continue another text" or "<p> this is a 2 lines long paragraph</p><p> which another p has DDD-12345 and long text</p>" inside of <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">

Comment: Also I have try to use replace but did not work as when I use "".join(html_as_list) the final result is something <!--\n/text and other text\n********\n--> ...etc so the replace() does not work

Comment: with `replace()` you have to find first element, replace it, next find second element, replace it, next find third element, replace it. You can't first find all elements and later replace them because every `replace()` moves other elements in different position. You could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments.

Comment: If my answer doesn't work in all situations then you could add more examples in question to better explain other situations.

Comment: if I remember correct replace() is a function which can be used for string, so I can use it for beautiful soup? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I add this line ```if result in html_as_str:
                html_as_str = html_as_str.replace(result, res_con)``` and it replaced the string only and not the whole tag. However I tried the same login to replace a tag with another and didnot work.

Comment: better show example HTML before and after changes - and if you have other tags inside `<td>` then show it too. it will be simpler to build correct code if you show  HTML.

Comment: Here is an example ```O:  <a class="external-link" href="https://jira_link/browse/DDDD-123" rel="nofollow">DDDD-123</a> U:  <!--<a class="external-link" href="https://jira_link/browse/DDDD-123" rel="nofollow">DDDD-123</a>-->
 #239125``` ... Using the same login should work but it does not.

Comment: put it in question - it will more readable, more peole will see it, and you can put longer example - with two or three `<td>` - I don't see any `<td>` in your example`. And you can put HTML **before** and **after** changes.

Comment: everything are on TD. My question is should replace work when both are str?

Comment: I still don't see `<td>` in your example - and all code starts with `find_all("td")`

Comment: meanwhile I made other example code and I put it in answer. But I don't know if it work with your `<td>` because you didn't show better example in question.